# vue js passing data to child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a child component `contactView` of the component `contacts-list`, which itself is a child. The problem is that I can not dynamically change the contents of this component

**html**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <component :is="currentView" keep-alive></component>
</div>
```

**js**

```
var IndexPage = Vue.component('index-page', {
  template: '<div>Welcome to index page</div>'
})

var Contact = Vue.component('contactView', {
  template: `
  <div class="person-info">
    <ul v-for="contact in contacts">
      <span>here</span>
      <li v-if="contact.email">
        <div class="icon icon-mail"></div>
        {{contact.email}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  `,
  props: ['contacts']
})

var ContactsList = Vue.component('contacts-list', {
  template: `
  <div id="list">
    list
    <div v-for="item in items">
        <div class="person">
            person
          <span class="name">{{item.name}}</span>
          <button class="trig">Show {{item.id}}</button>
        </div>
        <contact-view :contacts="item.contacts"> </contact-view>
    </div>
  </div>`,
  computed: {
    items: function(){
      return this.$parent.accounts
    }
  },
  components: {
    'contact-view': Contact
  }
})


var app = new Vue({
  el: '#wrapper',
  data: {
    contacts: [],
    currentView: 'index-page'
  }
})

app.currentView = 'contacts-list';
app.accounts = [{name: 'hello', id: 1}];

 $(document).on("click", "button.trig", function(){
    alert('triggered');
    app.accounts[0].contacts = [{email: '123@ya.ru'}]
})
```

After clicking on the button, the component does not display the changed data. How can I do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue [cannot detect](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats) when you add properties to an object dynamically. In this code,

```
app.accounts = [{name: 'hello', id: 1}];
```

You are adding the `accounts` property to the Vue dynamically. Instead, start with an empty array.

```
data: {
  contacts: [],
  currentView: 'index-page',
  accounts: []
}
```

Also in this code,

```
 $(document).on("click", "button.trig", function(){
    alert('triggered');
    app.accounts[0].contacts = [{email: '123@ya.ru'}]
})
```

you are adding the `contacts` property to an object that did not previously have a `contacts` property. If you change your code to this it will work.

```
 $(document).on("click", "button.trig", function(){
    alert('triggered');
    Vue.set(app.accounts[0],'contacts',[{email: '123@ya.ru'}])
})
```

I'm not sure why you are choosing to use jQuery to make these changes to your data, set the handler for your button, etc. All of these can be done with Vue.

Comment: JQuery is just an example. The method you proposed does not work for me, https://jsfiddle.net/mcfpgkyo/3/

Comment: @Marsel.V You are also adding `accounts` dynamically. I updated the answer. https://jsfiddle.net/mcfpgkyo/4/